# Add specific files to git branches

Tags: git

I am learning git and I came across the following situation.

I am having two folders `Work_DevCycle1` and `Work_DevCycle2`. I have to create two branches namely `userA/DevCycle1` and `userA/DevCycle2` and push them to the repository.

1. Work_DevCycle1 under userA/DevCycle1
2. Work_DevCycle2 under userA/DevCycle2 branches

My Approach:

First I am creating `Work_DevCycle1` folder, once after entire work is done I am using the following commands:

```
git branch userA/DevCycle1
git checkout userA/DevCycle1
git add Work_DevCycle1
git commit -m "Updated DevCycle1"
git push origin UserA/DevCycle1
```

Result:
`DevCycle1` is present under `userA/DevCycle1` branch

Now I am creating one more folder called `Work_DevCycle2`, once after entire work is done I am issuing the following commands:

```
git branch userA/DevCycle2
git checkout userA/DevCycle2
git add Work_DevCycle2
git commit -m "Updated DevCycle2"
git push origin UserA/DevCycle2
```

Result:
`Work_DevCycle1` and `Work_DevCycle2` are present under `userA/DevCycle2` branch.

What I want is instead to have `Work_DevCycle2` folder under `userA/DevCycle2` branch.

Can any body help me to sort out the issue ?

Thanks.